# how to add custom HTML in woocommerce breadcrumb?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I am working on WooCommerce breadcrumb. I just want to add span to home crumb. When i trying to do it, woocommerce removing it

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'change_breadcrumb' );
function change_breadcrumb( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['wrap_before'] = '<ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb1 animated wow slideInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">';
    $defaults['wrap_after'] = '</ol>';
    $defaults['before'] = '<li>';
    $defaults['after'] = '</li>';
    $defaults['delimiter'] = '';

    //add span tag
    $defaults['home'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>Home';

    return $defaults;

}
```

What do i get:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb1 animated wow slideInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>Groceries</li>
</ol>
```

What do i need:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb1 animated wow slideInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
    <li><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>Home</a></li>
    <li class="active">Groceries</li>
</ol>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZami.png)

And would be interesting how to add active class to non-home crumbs.

I think the answer is overriding breadcrumb.php

```
if(sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1){
    echo $before;
} else {
    echo $active;
}

if($key == 0){
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . $home . '</a>';
}
else if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
} else {
    echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
}
```

And i realized that i can add my own defaults

```
$defaults['active'] = '<li class="active">';
```

Comment: The `add_crumb()` method runs `strip_tags()` on your Home parameter thus removing the span you're trying to pass.

Answer (score 1):

well.. i suggest a twist on that. would it be possible to use the css3 selector :first-child? (as in tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) to set a background to the first li's link

```
ul.breadcrumb1:first-child a{
   Background:moo!
}
```

with proper padding you will obtain the same effect

Comment: I'm currently converting HTML to wordpress, and follow layout is very important for me

Comment: I think the right way is to override breacrumb.php and no need to change css